# Set Primary Key Value DB First Error

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

In a database-first Entity Framework setup, I have a composite primary key that includes two date time columns that I want to insert. Whenever I try and enter values on a insert for those two date columns, I get the following message

> Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected
>   number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since
>   entities were loaded. See
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=472540 for information on
>   understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.

I think this is because the columns are part of the primary key, but I still need to be able to insert values into the columns.

Is the only way to deal with this a stored procedure? Or is there a setting that will get around this error message. I don't have a option of changing the database schema

```
using (RubyEntities db = new RubyEntities())
{
    record = db.prcOpcoes.Create();
    record.division = division;
    record.opcoID = ocpoID;
    record.supplierNumber = supplierNumber;
    record.productID = productID;
    record.corpei = corpei;
    record.corpmktei = corpmktel;
    record.localei = localei;
    record.corpmkteiadj = OpcoMktEl;
    record.spoilage = spoilage;
    record.processingFee = processingFee;
    record.dateBegin = startDate;
    record.dateEnd = endDate;

    db.prcOpcoes.Add(record);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry SQL- Server I added screenshot of the EBMX and where I am setting the values of the date fields

Comment: are the other fields present in your EDMX but not in your INSERT optional (NOT NULL) in DB?

Comment: From error I can understand the issue is not related to the primary key, the issue could be  dbcontext holds data which are not up to date  with the database, may be there another thread or tool updating the database in the same time

Comment: if I comment out dateBegin and dateEnd it works fine

Comment: how can you INSERT after commenting out your PRIMARY KEY fields?

Comment: it inserts datetime.minvalue

Comment: Did you setup a DEFAULT value for those fields in table definition? Hope there are no triggers that are trying to modify those two columns.

Comment: no default and no triggers